# How to install 'xlsx' in R

Tags: java, r, excel

```
> library(**xlsx**)
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JVM could not be found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In system("/usr/libexec/java_home", intern = TRUE) :
  running command '/usr/libexec/java_home' had status 1
2: In fun(libname, pkgname) :
  Cannot find JVM library 'NA/lib/server/libjvm.dylib'
Install Java and/or check JAVA_HOME (if in doubt, do NOT set it, it will be detected)
```

#then I tried 'writexlx' but then that began giving me error messages

```
>BiocManager::install('**writexslx**')
Bioconductor version 3.11 (BiocManager 1.30.10), R 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Installing package(s) 'writexslx'
Warning message:
package ‘writexslx’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)
```

#I am not sure how to download this, please help
I evene tried to download jdk and that hasn't worked for me either.

Comment: have you tried re-installing Java? 
https://java.com/en/download/
Then you should be able to install it using `install.packages("xlsx")`

Comment: On my work pc I gave up with trying to use `xlsx` and used `openxlsx` which does not require Java and has much of the same functionality.

Comment: By `writexslx` do you mean `writexls`? That could be a source of *that* error.